# Uploading huge data when Sharepoint resource throttling is set

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, throttling

Do this throttle limit creates a problem when we upload bunch of items which exceeds throttle limit?

We have a .NET application which uploads pictures in sharepoint. Let's say the throttle limit is 2000 and we upload 5000 pictures, will this give an error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throttling limit has nothing to do with limiting number of items in a list.

It allows you to set a limit for how many rows of data can be retrieved for a list or library at any one time.

For more information read this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/27/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling.aspx)

Comment: Will this feature effect upload of data in the sharepoint if throttle limit is reached?

Comment: No, it won't. It only deals with retrieving data from lists.